# delete from two tables by using join statement, but there is an error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to delete the articles from `content` table, then in the same time delete the comments from `comments` table that related to these articles that deleted.

I have been created the following query:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM content JOIN comments ON content.id = comments.content_id WHERE content.delete_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

But I have this error:

```
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN comments ON content.id = comments.content_id WHERE delete_time < UNIX_TIMES' at line 1

DELETE FROM content JOIN comments ON content.id = comments.content_id WHERE delete_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

What is the wrong in the previous query?

Answer (score 1):

the best recommendation is to update the SQL FK from (on delete no action) to (on delete cascade) that will delete all the related rows over the SQL DB with just:

DELETE FROM tblContent
WHERE ArticleID = 'givenArticleID';

and this will take care of all the related rows in the DB.

another way is to delete first the related then to delete the father one.

Comment: I does not have id for these articles, that query will delete all articles that expired. I want in the same time delete the comments that related to each article.

Comment: Redesign your tables so each have `id` (autoincrement) use Islam's answer. And make sure you are running innoDB engine (because of the keys).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a proper syntax for a joined delete query

```
DELETE content.*,comments.*
 FROM content 
INNER JOIN comments ON content.id = comments.content_id 
WHERE content.delete_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

This way you can delete the rows from your content table and the rows related to each content where the delete_time is less than UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),but make sure you first test the queries on your demo data not directly on production data

Comment: Thanks, your query works well  in delete each article with its comments, but it does not work well in delete all expired articles. unfortunately, it deletes some expired articles, not all expired articles

Comment: As with no data set to test i can't say anything if possible can you provide the sample data set example using http://sqlfiddle.com/ and alsomg with the data set to be deleted it will be good to analyze it with some testing data